# Selenium WebDriver testing login verification

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to use Visual Studio MVC3 with C# and Selenium Webdriver to test field verification on a login page.  I need the Selenium script to be able to tell if a login fails by the error text displayed.  What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have selenium log in, then look for some text on the page, or if the warning/error text is inside an element, you could use something like -

```
element.Text.Equals("text");
```

Of course this is really generic without you showing any code.

Comment: Also, if it redirects to another page than it's a success.